# SQL Server CASE clause on where inside parenthesis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this problem in my SQL code:

I will only show my `WHERE` clause, because it is a bit long,
this is it:

```
where 
 ((@account_status = 1027 AND a.AccountStatus = 1027  AND a.FolioNo = 
  @folio_no AND b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id)) OR
 ((@account_status = 1026 AND a.AccountStatus = 1026  AND a.FolioNo = 
 @folio_no AND b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id)) OR
 ((@account_status = 1025 AND a.AccountStatus = 1025 AND @trans_code = 1 AND 
 a.AccountStatementTransCode = 1 AND b.FolioNo = @folio_no AND 
 b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id)) OR
 ((@account_status = 1025 AND a.AccountStatus = 1025 AND @trans_code != 1 
 AND a.AccountStatementTransCode != 1 AND b.FolioNo = @folio_no AND 
 b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id)) OR
 ((a.FolioNo = @folio_no AND b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id AND 
 @trans_code = 2 AND a.AccountStatementTransCode = 2 AND 
 case
   when @sub_category = 14 then i.category_id is null
    else i.category_id = @sub_category 
 end )) OR
 ((a.FolioNo = @folio_no AND b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id AND 
 @trans_code = 3 AND a.AccountStatementTransCode = 3 AND i.category_id = 
 @sub_category)) OR
 ((a.FolioNo = @folio_no AND b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id AND 
 @trans_code = 4 AND a.AccountStatementTransCode = 4 AND i.category_id = 
 @sub_category)) OR
 ((a.FolioNo = @folio_no AND b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id AND 
 @trans_code = 5 AND a.AccountStatementTransCode = 5 AND i.category_id = 
 @sub_category)) OR
 ((a.FolioNo = @folio_no AND b.ReservationNo = @reservation_id AND 
 @trans_code = 6 AND a.AccountStatementTransCode = 6 AND i.category_id = 
 @sub_category))
```

I want that if input is `@sub_category = 14` then it will return the category with `NULL` values, else it will return the `@sub_category` values.
How can I do that ?

Comment: It's usually better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in WHERE clauses.

Comment: A lot of those where's looks like they could be simplified. I'd properly start with that before adding more logic.

Comment: This question is already answered by jaydipj thank you everyone for answering :) i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace CASE expression logic with below

```
AND 
1 = CASE WHEN @sub_category = 14 AND i.category_id is null 
         THEN 1
         WHEN @sub_category <> 14 AND i.category_id = @sub_category 
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END
```

Comment: it works sir! thanks alot! this is the very first time i encountered a case on where clause so it really takes me long enough to get rid of it! it works properly man by the way i wanna ask what is the use of 1's and 0's sir?

Comment: @GGw Glad to help you!!. Ans to your question is, 1 and 0 are just return values when your condition's are satisfying then return 1 else 0. then this return value is used for equality check. like 1 = (return value 1 or 0) and based of this result data get filtered.

Comment: ohhh! thats why coz i really want to try that stuff with 1 and 0 but i was afraid that it will literally return 1 and 0 lol

Answer (score 1):

Change your `CASE` to:

```
case
    when @sub_category = 14 then null
    else i.category_id = @sub_category 
 end
```

Comment: `i.category_id = @sub_category ` this line causes problem.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: Simple way, If your `category_id` never hold `-1` or you can use the value that will never be in `category_id` i.e. `0,-1`

```
AND ISNULL(i.category_id, -1) = CASE WHEN @sub_category = 14 THEN 
                                    -1 
                                ELSE @sub_category END
```